# Вопрос по faults в cPanel шаред-хостинга

Tags: php, сервер, хостинг, администрирование

В общем с увеличением посещаемости начали проблемы на хостинге. Как я понимаю из-за недостающего параметра `Entry processes`, на данный момент это значение равно 30.

Что представляет из себя сайт - php-движок, думаю нагрузку он дает несущественную (есть аналогичные), есть форма поиска, которая при помощи `curl` ищет инфу на других сайтах и выдает юзеру.

Хостера теребил по поводу зашкаливающего 30/30 `Entry processes`, ответ: `Количество запущенных процессов может накапливается когда скрипты зацикливаются, либо пытаются получить доступ с каких-то внешних ресурсов, который в данный момент недоступны.`

**Мои вопросы:**

1. Равно ли faults на скрине не загруженной странице сайта? То есть 23000 faults равно ли тому, что пользователи загрузили страницы сайта и увидели ошибку `5хх Resource Limit Is Reached` именно эти 23000 раз?
2. Правильно ли я понимаю, что пользователи создающие формой curl-запросы и плодят эти `Entry processes`? Из-за того что на эти curl-запросы долго приходит ответ и `Entry processes` не успевают отработать?

Скрины прикреплены ниже.

[image: Скрин 1]
[image: Скрин 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что пользователи создающие формой curl-запросы и плодят эти Entry processes?  Из-за того что на эти curl-запросы долго приходит ответ и Entry processes не успевают отработать?

Не видя вашего сайта целиком однозначно утвержать сложно. У вас хостинг не Cloudlinux? (т.е это выделенный сервак с выделенным кол-ом ресурсов который потребляет именно ваш сайт, или ресурсы потребляют и соседние сайты других пользователей?). На каком кол-ве сайтов ищите? curl_multi не используете?)

Если предпологать что проблема именно в CURL - то вполне возможно что если у вас таймаут не установлен то можно предположить следующую ситуацию:

У вас всего 30 entry process. Зашел человек на сайт ввел запрос...Запрос обратился к сайту (у которого перегруз по траффику или проблемы с хостингом)..Вы ждете от него ответ..у вас висит 1 процесс..Потом этотже человек обновляет страницу вводит еще один запрос и создает второй процесс.. Потом еще 28 людей заходят и делают поиск в течении скажем 1-2 минут..у вас первышен лимит 30 одновременно запущенных процессов...

Решение: Обрубать висящие процессы, чем быстрее будете обрубать тем мало вероятней что за N секунд появится 30 людей который обратятся к перегруженному сайту. (т..е тут должно совпасть 2 условия №1 - 30 людей у вас на сайте ищут чтото в течении N сек №2 - удаленный сайт должен иметь перегрузку, чтобы не дать вам ответ в эти самые 10 сек)...Уменьшая время ожидания вы откладываете проблему на будущее т.е. это временное решение...

**Решения:**

**№1)** Увеличить Entry process

**№2)** Уменьшить время ожидания CURL (прибивая процессы)

Попробуйте установить данные параметры для CURL:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 20)
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10
```

**№3)** Рекомендую сделать получение всей инфы с тех сайтов по крону, и чтобы пользователи искали информацию которую вы уже слили с тех сайтов пару часов назад. Т.е раз в 3-4 часа вы сливаете всю информацию с удаленных ресурсов..Все пользователи ищут информацию уже у вас (без никаких внешних обращений). Преимущества подхода - нагрузка будет в разы меньше, не потребляется траффик при поиске пользователей, информация всегда доступна. Не нужно увеличения ENTRY PROCESS и т.д

**№4)** Проверять сайт на недоступность перед каждым запросом поиска(или даже лучше не перед каждым,а перед каждым 5-10ым запросом), если сайт не доступен ставите флаг, который актуален скажем 5-10 мин, пока флаг актуален при поиске любого юзера поиск не производить, а выдавать всем сообщение - повторите запрос через N минут..

Обязательно заведите логи....которые пишут сколько посетителей было...в какое время.....что слали...возможно вашу форму поиска просто ктото задосил....капчу же надеюсь не забыли поставить для поиска?

Comment: да, именно Cloudlinux, curl_multi не использую. Как обрубывать процессы, что вы имеете в виду? данные приходят быстро, 1-2 сек. Другое дело, что я не отслеживаю доступность сайтов, может они были недоступны и поэтому появились висяки? Да, пожалуй, попробую таймауты, я их пока не использовал.  Крон не пойдет, запросы каждый раз разные, но иногда повторяются, хочу сделать кеширование запрос-ответов в базу данных, но пока слабоват в php и времени маловато.

Comment: Тогда делаете таймауты невысокие...если не поможет...тогда нада будет перед отправкой запроса проверять сайт на доступность и если сайт не доступен блокать всем остальным юзерам возможность поиска на N минут...

Comment: Entry processes - это кол-во паралельно висящих процессов, т.е если все хорошо то скрипты так бытро отрабатывают что процесс умирает за считанные доли секунды и свободен для выполнения опять...в вашем случает 30 процессов заняты и не освобождаются....